# ruby Fail to load readline

Tags: irb, tab-completion

I intend to use `Tab Completion`, then I try to load `readline` using the following command:

```
$ irb -r irb/completion
```

However, irb throws an error message shown below:

```
/usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require':LoadError: cannot load such file -- readline
```

Then I try to install readline using command:

```
gem install readline
```

But, RubyGems prompt me that

`ERROR:  Could not find a valid gem 'readline' (>= 0) in any repository`

How can I fix it?

Comment: https://rubygems.org/gems/rb-readline rb-readline

Comment: @RonniSkansing, thanks! Your advice works for me. Please post your answer and I will accept your answer as the best answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have been troubled by the naming.

The repo name is rb-readline

Answer (score 2):

You need to have the readline libraries installed when you compile Ruby.

Follow this blog: http://vvv.tobiassjosten.net/ruby-on-rails/fixing-readline-for-the-ruby-on-rails-console/

Comment: What if I don't want to re-install ruby?